# Injecting service to another service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement login module to AngularJS app. I try to call UserService from (this) authenticationService but UserService is undefined. What am I doing wrong now, why UserService is undefined?

```
var authenticationService = angular.module('authenticationService', []);

authenticationService.factory('authenticationSvc', ['$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'UserService',

function AuthenticationService($scope, $http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout, UserService) {
    var service = {};

    service.Login = Login;
    service.SetCredentials = SetCredentials;
    service.ClearCredentials = ClearCredentials;

    return service;

function Login(username, password, callback) {
        var response;

        UserService.GetByUsername(username) //UserService is unidefined!!!
                .then(function (user) {
                    if (user !== null && user.password === password) {
                        response = { success: true };
                    } else {
                        response = { success: false, message: 'Username or password is incorrect' };
                    }
                    callback(response);
                });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : Take a look at your dependency injection: you should have the same number of elements in the dependency array as the number of arguments in your function. You inject `$scope` in the array, and not in the arguments. You should always inject every dependency in both, and in the right order: here, Angular thinks `$scope` corresponds to your `$http` argument, the `$http` service corresponds to your `$cookieStore` argument, and so on, until `UserService` that refers to the 6th element of the dependency array which is... undefined.

Try

```
authenticationService.factory('authenticationSvc', ['$scope','$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'UserService',

    function AuthenticationService($scope, $http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout, UserService) {
    ...
    }
]);
```

Instead.

Also, with this line

```
 var authenticationService = angular.module('authenticationService', []);
```

You create a new module that has no dependencies (`[]`) my guess is that `UserService` is defined in another module, that is not injected in the present service module nor in the app's main module, thus unavailable.

For the record : `angular.module(name,array)` *creates* a new module, which depends on the modules passed in the array. `angular.module(name)` *retreives* a previously created module.

I don't think you *need* a new module for a single service though. If you define your Authentication service in the same module as your `UserService`, it will be available by default.

EDIT : Plus, be careful with your naming pattern : for instance, given your code, if I wanted to include the authentication service as a service dependency, I would have to include `authenticationSvc` and not `authenticationService`...

Comment: so when I am calling factory and trying to add dependency to UserService then, it is not enough?

Comment: It would be enough if they were in the same module. But they're not. Instead you have to inject the module as a module dependency, then the service itself as a service dependency.

Comment: @Sami Tiesselune is correct, by suggested design you should keep all your services in the same module

Comment: Still the same error :( TypeError: Cannot read property 'GetByUsername' of undefined. In my "design" every service is in own file, when using ngResource, I haven't got this problem

Comment: Actually, I think I know what's wrong here. I'm updating my answer right away.